# The %unit in css is not working in my sample code

Tags: html, css

I have written a small sample code where I am using %unit with the understanding that the %unit ensures the % of its parent. but when I see the output, it does not seem to work.
For my understanding I was looking into the link [Relative Units](https://thecssworkshop.com/lessons/relative-units#:%7E:text=In%20the%20specification%20the%20relative,according%20to%20some%20other%20value.)
I have a file structure like...
In the main folder, I have Styles folder and SearchCard.html. With in styles folder, I have style.css.
Here's my full code.

```css
.searchcardcontainer {
  width: 80vw;
  min-height: 32px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.searchcardcontainer .searchcard {
  margin: 5px 3px 3px 2px;
  width: 80%;
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 96px;
  background-color: #00b672;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 90vw;
  max-width: 940px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.wrapper .inner {
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/style.css">
  <title>Search Card</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="searchcardcontainer">
    <div id="search-card-01" class="searchcard">

    </div>
    <div id="search-card-02" class="searchcard">

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>This div takes up 90% of the viewport width to a maximun of 940px.</p>
    <div class="inner">
      <p>The nested div is set to 50%. This makes it 50% of its direct parent.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This looks perfect at first sight. But when I do inspect from google chrome and set the width to 320 and height to 480, it looks like the %unit has no effect. The wrapper and wrapper inner is working fine as provided in example in the above referred website. Could someone point me to what's the mistake that I am doing?

Comment: Can you explain the issue a little further, this works for me even as I adjust the page width. What you do you mean when you say you set the width to 320 and the height to 480 in chrome? Viewing this at that size is still showing the nested div as about 50% of 90vw to me.

Comment: note that for `.searchcard ` you have specified a `min-width` which could cause some confusion

Comment: You are using min-width: 300px; in .searchcard that's why it has no effect.

Comment: Yes. I commented min-width and it now works as expected. Thanks lastr2d2 and Beshambher Chaukhwan

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I commented min-width and it now works as expected. Thanks lastr2d2 and Beshambher Chaukhwan